# USB boot option disappeared

Tags: usb, boot

I have a Dell XPS 14z which I am trying to install Linux Mint 13 on.  I know this computer can boot off USB drives; I've done it before, however the option to boot off a USB has disappeared from the BIOS menu.  The only options I have are CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive, Hard Drive, and Network.  How do I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

The USB device has to be plugged in before you enter BIOS Setup utility to have this option available, most likely

Comment: I have the usb plugged in though